# How to compute the correlation coefficient between continuous and discrete variables ?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, random-variable

Is there any adjustment required when computing the correlation coefficient between:

- continuous and discrete variable
- two discrete variables ?

Thanks !

Comment: [This site](http://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/math/edrm611/edrm13.htm) has a convenient list of possible correlation measures, as does [this document](http://www.napce.org/documents/research-design-yount/22_correlation_4th.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Pearson's correlation coefficient is defined for continuous variables. You can test dependence, which is a broader concept than correlation, between discrete random variables using a Chi squared test for independence. If you have a continuous variable you can "discretize" it by creating ranges.

Comment: I think that's too strong a statement in at least two senses. 1. In principle, Pearson correlation could be applied to two counted variables, for example. It is perhaps unlikely that would often be useful, but that's not the main point. If linearity of relationship makes sense, Pearson correlation can be applied. 2. Chi-square testing is a weak form of analysis if one or both variables is discrete but ordinal.

Comment: -1 In addition to the points already made, discretizing is generally a bad idea and a test is not what was asked here.

Comment: @Gala - Intuitively I see why discretization is a bad idea, but do you have any references regarding some analysis which shows why discretization is a bad idea -- perhaps through some case studies or something?